App Crash Android 14 : One of RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED should be specifcation
**> Hello
I am using io.agora.rtc:chat-sdk:1.2.0 for chat in my android application. While running app on Android 14 device app crash and giving me below error:
java.lang.SecurityException: One of RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED should be specified when a receiver isn't being registered exclusively for system broadcasts android
Can anyone please help me to solve this. Thanks in advance.**
java.lang.SecurityException: com.example: One of RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED should be specified when a receiver isn't being registered exclusively for system broadcasts                                                                                     android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:3071)                                                                             at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:3055)                                                                                                 android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:3038                                                                                          at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2980                                                                                            atandroid.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.registerReceiverWithFeature(IActivityManager.java:6380)    

the 1.2.1 version has included this bug fix, see https://docs.agora.io/en/agora-chat/overview/release-notes?platform=android

RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED is required when registering a broadcast listener for apps targeting android 14 and above.
It should look something like this
context.registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter, RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED);
However, it you are not the one registering but a third-party library is then cross check once if you are using the latest version of that library. If there is a new version use that, but if there is no new version then you cannot use that library on apps that target android 14 and above.
